# how do i direct to my folder that my .cmd is in, in cmd

Tags: command-line, jar

The question i'm asking is weird way of wording it, and maybe that's why I cant find this problem anywhere else. If this question has already been answers would you kindly direct me to the answer.

What i'm trying to do is run a .JAR file from cmd. which I know how to do with the 
java -jar .jar 
command. But what I cant figure out how to do is find the folder that the .cmd file and .jar file is in. Its confusing. I know.

Comment: Have you tried ls/dir? Or cd with no args?

Comment: Wow. I feel really dumb now. TY so much

Answer (score 1):

I guess I can just do cd with no args. That seems to work. Feeling really dumb right about now.

Comment: If this works, mark it as answered... - though if that is the case offer @garrigan to post it as answer and let her have the credit

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off &:: check_current_dir.bat
echo in execute path: "%cd%"
pushd "%~dp0"
echo in this .bat dir: "%cd%"
popd
echo out od this .bat dir:
cd
pause
```

Comment: You can make your answers even better when you add explanatory text. Show us that you deserve the rep gained in the last few minutes ;-)